# How does "ChangeNotifierProxyProvider" work in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-provider

Considering the following code:

```
providers: [
   ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth()),
   ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Entries>(
      create: (_) => Entries(),
      update: (_, auth, previousEntries) => Entries(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousEntries == null ? [] : previousEntries.items,
     ),
   ),
],
```

Where do `aut` and `previousEntries` come from?

Although I guess `auth` comes from `ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth())` line of the code and it's actually `var auth = Provider.of<Auth>(Context);` that has been created automatically, but don't have any ideas where does `previousEntries` come from?

Comment: Both `auth` and `previousEntries` come from the code that calls the `update` function you're defining.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I still can't understand how `previousEntries` gets here? Could you write an example in answers?